# converting php array to json

Tags: php, json

I am playing around with Slack /commands, 
The given json that needs to be sent back to slack looks like this.

```
{
 "text" : "hello world",
  "attachments": [{
                  "text" : " this is information"

                 }]
}
```

I am trying to replicate this  doing it in this way.

```
$data = array(
        "text" => "hello world",
        "attachments" => array(
            "text" => "this is information",
            "author_name" => "masnad"
        )
    ); 

$this->output->set_content_type('application/json');
return $this->output->set_output(json_encode($data));
```

I just can't get the square brackets to work so the slack understands.

Comment: The requested JSON is wrong. You need curly brackets.

Comment: @RahulMeshram I tried json_encode, does not work, you cant just give a negative point for that.

Comment: I didn't. Huhhh. I retracted my duplication on your question instead! How can you just!!! Please

Comment: @RahulMeshram sorry, thought it was you, my bad.

Comment: @VincentMimoun-Prat I added the curly brackets to the slack json part, since I wrote it manually forgot to add it there.

Comment: @AlivetoDie I checked it out and thanks a lot!
Since Vincent answered first I think the tick should rightfully go to him.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wrap each attachment within an array

```
$data = array(
    "text" => "hello world",
    "attachments" => array(
        array( "text" => "this is information" ),
        array( "text" => "this is another information" ),
    )
);
```

With modern PHP, and for the sake of readability, you should use the square brackets notation for arrays:

```
$data = [
    "text" => "hello world",
    "attachments" => [
        [ "text" => "this is information" ],
        [ "text" => "this is another information" ],
    ]
];
```